# Variable 'per' not in scope error in XQuery

Tags: xquery

I am getting 'Variable 'per' not in scope error' error, when I tried to execute below code in Java.

```
  String xq = "declare variable $per1 as document-node(element(*, xs:untyped)) := " +
    "fn:parse-xml($per);" +
  "declare variable $job1 as document-node(element(*, xs:untyped)) := fn:parse-xml($job);" +
    "for $i in $per1//pimergednodes/Get__CompIntfc__CI_PERSONAL_DATAResponse,\n" + 
  "         $j in $job1//jobmergednodes/Get__CompIntfc__CI_JOB_DATAResponse[PROP_EMPLID = $i/PROP_EMPLID]\n" + 
  "\n" + 
  "     return\n" + 
  "        <emp>\n" + 
  "        {\n" + 
  "           $i/PROP_EMPLID,\n" + 
  "           $i/PROP_BIRTHDATE,\n" + 
  "           <coll_names>\n" + 
  "           {\n" + 
  "           $i/COLL_NAME_TYPE_VW/COLL_NAMES\n" + 
  "           }\n" + 
  "           </coll_names>,\n" + 
  "\n" + 
  "           $i/PROP_BIRTHDATE/COLL_NAME_TYPE_VW/PROP_FIRST_NAME,\n" + 
  "           $j/COLL_JOB/PROP_DEPTID\n" + 
  "\n" + 
  "           }\n" + 
  "        </emp>";

  XQDataSource xds = new oracle.xquery.xqj.OXQDataSource();
  XQConnection conn = xds.getConnection();
  XQPreparedExpression pEx = conn.prepareExpression(xq); ==> error raised in this call.
```

Can somebody help me in fixing this error.

Thanks In Advance,
Maviswa

Comment: I am getting the impression you are trying to pass in $per and $job from Java context into the XQuery context. You will need to do a little more, like declaring them as external, and passing them in somehow to your XQuery Java objects. You could also just concatenate the literal XML into your query..

Answer (score 0):

You reference $per in fn:parse-xml($per), but your code doesn't define that variable anywhere. I see $per1, but no $per. I suspect you'll run into the same problem with $job.

For debugging, print out the xq string so you can see the XQuery by itself without all the Java string escaping, which just adds a lot of noise.